# Codeigniter: on zip upload error: ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-web-services, file-upload, zip

I am uploading zip file using CI upload library. The code is working fine at my local server but not working on AWS server. When I try to upload a zip file on server it shows `ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED` issue. 
[image]
If I instead try to upload a single image file then it doesn't show the above issue.

The upload configuration is as below:

```
$config['allowed_types']    = 'zip|rar';
$config['max_size']         = '5000000';
$config['max_width']        = '102400';
$config['max_height']       = '768000';
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

Also, I have change mimes.php file as below:

```
'zip'   =>  array('application/x-zip', 'application/zip', 'application/x-zip-compressed', 'application/s-compressed', 'multipart/x-zip','application/octet-stream')
'rar'   =>  array('application/x-rar', 'application/rar', 'application/x-rar-compressed','application/octet-stream')
```

My CI version:`3.1.6`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change settings in your php.ini file.Increase: max_execution_time, max_input_time, upload_max_filesize and post_max_size

Comment: It doesn't seem to be an error related to file size as If I try to upload a zip file of mere 400 kbs, its still not working for me.

Comment: try $config['allowed_type'] = 'application/zip';